# Creating an instance of a class with ()

Tags: c++, class, constructor, most-vexing-parse

I have a question : what constructor is used when you create an instance of a class with `ClassName instance()` in C++ ?

Example:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Test
{
private:
    Test()
    {
        cout << "AAA" << endl;
    }

public:
    Test(string str)
    {
        cout << "String = " << str << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Test instance_1(); // instance_1 is created... using which constructor ?
    Test instance_2("hello !"); // Ok

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Tricky! You would expect compilation to fail as default constructor is private. However, it compiles and nothing is created. The reason?

```
Test instance_1();
```

... is just a function declaration! (Which returns `Test` and takes nothing.)

Comment: That is what I was about to say, but you beat me to it. This is C++ most vexing parse (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

Comment: most vexing parse is a very apt name! and questions under this tag http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/most-vexing-parse are an excellent proof.

Answer (score 7):

The statement `Test instance_1();` doesn't call a constructor at all, because it's not defining a variable - instead, it's declaring a function called `instance_1` that returns an object of type `Test`. To create an instance using the 0-argument constructor, you'd use `Test instance_1;`.

Comment: Or the new C++0x syntax -> Test instance_1{};